# How to keep browser from changing my camera settings?

Tags: google-chrome, camera, webcam

I have a Logitech USB webcam. On Zoom, it's set correctly to just show my face. I joined some sort of browser teleconference platform (in Chrome) and the camera was showing the whole room (much wider than normal). I couldn't figure out how to set it back; I tried a Camera Settings application which sets it, but the Chrome platform changes it right back. What are my options to make sure this doesn't happen - is there a way to get control and override what the browser is asking the camera to do?  Is there a "virtual camera" method that lets me set the video stream properties before it gets to Chrome?

Comment: Get OBS Studio and use its virtual cam feature.

Comment: Ok I just did, and Zoom sees the virtual camera, but Chrome does not - I'm using remo.co web conferencing page, and it shows my USB camera but not the virtual camera.

Comment: Try Webcam Settings (from the App Store). It adjusts the webcam without the need for any virtual webcam. This won't block Chrome messing it up, but may allow you to get control afterwards.